# How to correctly scale view

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I'm wondering what is the best way to correcly scale a view in Windows 10 / Windows 8(.1) application.

- ViewBox ?
- VisualStateManager ?
- Other ?

My picture are already suffixed by .scale-xxx.png

In 1366x768, I have :
[image]

And in WXGA, I have :
[image]

Here is my xaml code :

```
 <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="6*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Player, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

    <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="ms-appx:///Resources/Title/title-app.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,5,25,5">
        <Image Source="ms-appx:///Resources/Rating/star-full.png" Stretch="None"  />
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5,5,0,0" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Stars, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's the VisualStateManager because here you can find the
AdaptiveTrigger with MaxWindowWidth or MinWindowWidth. Then the diffrent VisulaStates will work perfectly.

For Example:

```
 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Width1250">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1310"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="Button1.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Target="Button2.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Target="Button3.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                 </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
```

Hope to help you :)

Comment: `AdaptiveTrigger` wasn't available in Windows 8.1 (which was mentioned in the question).

Comment: Yes this is true, you have to choose which OS you use. I'm working on a UWP  for Windows 10 because of that I prefer the `AdaptiveTrigger`.

Comment: It's a great solution if you can require Windows 10+.

Answer (score 0):

As blueeyes said you can achieve this using visual states. If you don't want to change design you can simply use viewbox to fit the resolution (with stretching).